# Wrong tick location when I set the x-axis labels manually in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have been trying to plot two vectors against some `x` values on the same graph. And I want to set the numerical `x` labels manually, as characters. But the final result looks weird.

```
vars = {'50', '100', '250', '500'};
inducing_p = linspace(1,4,4);
ind_table_mse = [0.9051 0.8911 0.8770 0.8688];
ind_table_mseF = [0.9155 0.9070 0.8796  0.8708];


plot(inducing_p, ind_table_mse);
hold on;
plot(inducing_p, ind_table_mseF);
title('ASA Flight Delay Dataset','interpreter','latex');
xlabel('Inducing points','interpreter','latex');
ylabel('MSE','interpreter','latex');
set(gca,'XTickLabel',vars);
xtickangle(45);
```

And I get this graph, which is not at all of what I indented. As, I would like to see only `50 100 250 500` labels on `x`. Any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have first to modify the location of the ticks in your figure

```
figure
plot(inducing_p, ind_table_mse);
hold on;
plot(inducing_p, ind_table_mseF);
title('ASA Flight Delay Dataset','interpreter','latex');
xlabel('Inducing points','interpreter','latex');
ylabel('MSE','interpreter','latex');
set(gca,'XTick',[1 2 3 4]); %%%% HERE
set(gca,'XTickLabel',vars);
xtickangle(45);
```

The weird behavior is indeed due to the fact that you specify less labels than ticks. So Matlab just repeats them.

Comment: Maybe I should also change the title. To be more specific to the problem.